# Bash while loop and reading from pipe

Tags: shell, pipe, scheduling

I have a Windows command-line program that I'm running in a Bash script in Ubuntu via wine. The Bash script basically looks like this:

```
wine myprogram.exe | while read line
do
   # Process line
done
```

Now, since I've written myprogram.exe I know for a fact that it just spits out data as fast as it can. Can anyone explain to me how the Bash while loop is able to process the data in case my program spits it out faster than the while loop can handle? Is there some sorcery going on behind the scenes where the kernel scheduler will make myprogram.exe sleep if it produces too much data? Anyone? Currently I'm leaning towards it being black magic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the program may do its own output buffering. This is sometimes called “[stdio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output) buffering” after the name of the library component that performs this task in C: the functions like `putc`, `fputs`, `fprintf`, etc., declared in `stdio.h`. If it does, it will produce output in bursts, typically of a few kilobytes (when the output is a terminal, the default is to flush the buffer at each newline character).

At some point, either the programmer or the underlying library function calls [`write`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) explicitly. This requests that the kernel write the specified data into the pipe. The kernel may decide to write all or part of the data. Since the file is a pipe, the kernel will copy the data into the pipe's buffer area. If the pipe buffer is full, then the `write` system call blocks until there is room: your program (or more precisely, the thread that called `write`, in case there are several kernel-level threads) will not resume execution until the call to `write` returns.

(It is possible, but unlikely in this situtation, that the program has set the pipe's file descriptor as [non-blocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O). If this is the case, if the kernel determines that it can't copy any data, it will return control to the program; the `write` system call returns 0. A program that makes such non-blocking system calls would typically call [`select`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28Unix%29) or `poll` or [`epoll`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll) in a loop to block until one of the file descriptors it's communicating on is ready for input or output.)

The fact that the program is blocked during a system call is not related to a choice of scheduling algorithm. At its core, any [scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29) distinguishes between *ready* threads, which can be given CPU time, and *waiting* threads, which cannot. The gist of a scheduler is to choose a ready thread, and let it run until either the thread makes a system call (which puts the thread into a waiting state) or some asynchronous event occurs (in practice, a processor [interrupt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt)). During the processing of a system call, it may be that a thread that was until then blocked becomes ready, for example because that thread was in a `write` call and the kernel has now been able to deliver the data from that call. A few things can make a ready thread blocked from the outside, for example a [signal to pause (`SIGSTOP`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctrl-Z). The scheduler maintains some kind of *ready list* to decide which thread to schedule next: a list of threads that are ready (it is usually a lot more complicated than a simple list in a real-world scheduler).

Answer (score 2):

It's called a pipe. Run `man 7 pipe` and you will learn all about how pipes work.

*Edited to add:*
In brief, the wine command's output is collected in a buffer. When the buffer is full and wine attempts to write more, the wine process is stopped by the kernel. When space becomes available in the buffer (ie. when the while loop reads from it), the stopped process is reawoken and it is allowed to continue. This is the classic bounded-buffer algorithm, but in the Unix/Linux world it's usually called a pipe. It's very popular and powerful, and I recommend learning all about it.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but "RTFM" is the sort of response I'd expect on Slashdot. Granted, RTFM is probably an answer that works on most questions with zero effort required.

Comment: @Magnus Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't mean this to come off as a gruff RTFM. The question seeks an explanation and the explanation that is most relevant to the questioner is handily available in that man page, so it seemed to be the optimal answer.

Comment: Ok, I've read the man page now, and it seems that the behavior depends on whether the O_NONBLOCK flag was set or not. I guess I will just run the script and see if it blows up.

Comment: If you don't want wine to block without losing data, you can install a program called `buffer` and run it in the pipeline with any buffer size your system will handle. Obviously, with enough output you'll eventually have to compromise and either lose writes or allow wine to block; but `buffer` will let you stretch it out and survive larger bursts of output.

Comment: It's running right now with I guess the standard buffer size of 64K and seems to work so far... I have 16 GB of memory on this box, so if it fails I will try your suggestion =)

Answer (score 1):

Nah, no black magic (well not this time at least).  It just uses your cache and buffers in the output stream.

Comment: And what happens when the buffer is full?

Comment: Don't you mean: Yeah, black magic, otherwise known as a buffer. @Magnus, when the receiving buffer is full, attempts to write to stdout in Unix block. I don't know anything about Windows programming, so I can't say how wine passes that on to myprogram.exe.

Comment: I'm not a Linux programming guru... when you say that the write blocks, does that mean that the kernel notes that the program is trying to write to a full stdout buffer, and will then suspend the thread and only wake it up once the pipe is no longer full?

Comment: @Magnus In *nix a program writing to stdout is the same as writing to a file. When the application prints output, it is making a write() system call to file descriptor 1. The operation will not complete until write() is finished, at that point it is "blocked".